# phaser , Circle button

Tags: javascript, game-engine, phaser-framework

im trying to make a circle button with tap event i used hitArea property from sprite class and using pixi Circle class i did that

```
this.sprite = game.add.sprite(50,50,"cursors");

        this.sprite.anchor.set(0.5,0.5);

        this.sprite.hitArea = new PIXI.Circle(50,50,84);

        this.sprite.inputEnabled = true;

        this.sprite.events.onInputDown.add(function(){

            console.log("clicked");
        });

    };
```

it is not working at all
so i tried removing  `this.sprite.anchor.set(0.5,0.5);`

input is work fine when there is no hit Area so what should i do

note :
phaser version is 2.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve it by siting

```
new PIXI.Circle(0,0,84);
```

x and y must be x o the inner sprite not it x axis in the stage

i answered it if it will be useful or someone else .